# Can I use an ethernet splitter or switch to connect a pc & tv with a SKY Q mini box?

Tags: networking

Have recently had a SKY Q box installed with a mini box upstairs. The latest SKY boxes have only one ethernet port: So the question is "Can I use an ethernet splitter or switch to connect a pc & tv with a SKY Q mini box?" This is a man cave set up so is vitally important!!

Comment: If it's standard Ethernet, then of course. But a switch, never a splitter.

Comment: Does the switch turn one connection off and another on or does it share?

Comment: https://computer.howstuffworks.com/lan-switch.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should work if you are only connection a tv and computer. If you are connecting any more devices via Ethernet, then I would recommend you get a new box that has more Ethernet ports.